# In app purchase testing

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have my first app launched just now.  I was putting an in-app purchase but it got really difficult so I commented it out and submitted a version to itunes connect without the upgrade, just to get it started.   While i was waiting for approval I made a bit of headway, had my store collecting the SKresponse etc, but then my app got approved and now my in-app purchase went to a yellow light and I can no longer test with it.

What can I do ?  It says I have to upload more code to get it to go green light again, but I had it green light before I even had any code up there..

thanks so much for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In itunes connect, create a new version of the app. Afterwards click Manage In-App purchases and it should be alright.

If it's still locked, create another in-app purchase item/product and use that, then remove the original one.